# CRM 2013: Update a read-only field value using Business Rule

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to calculate a date field value based on another field, using the Business Rule feature in CRM 2013. The field is locked on the Form so that the user cannot modify. I think because of this setting, the field value is bet set initially however when I click the 'Save' button the value disappears.

I believe this is the same as `setSubmitMode("always")` issue for read-only fields. I am wondering if there is a way to resolve this issue inside the Business Rule or Form/Field settings ?

Comment: You must `setSubmitMode('always')` or CRM won't save disabled fields (data won't be picked up and sent to the server)

Comment: CRM only saves fields that are marked as 'dirty'. Disabled fields can never be 'dirty'

Comment: I think you should suggest this as a feature improvement on the Connect site: https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/Feedback

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem but I found this workaround:

> The workaround is to add the locked field twice on the form.  Make 1
>   instance of the field 'read only' and 'visible' and then make the 2nd
>   instance of the field NOT 'read only' and NOT 'visible' on the form. 
>   then when the Business Rules fire it will see that one of the
>   instances of the field is not read only and then save to the database.
>
> Source: 
>   https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/741916de-e637-40f1-a675-944e7c0f5130/crm-2013-business-rules-updating-read-only-fields?forum=crm